# PHP DATA OBJECT IN DIFFERENT CLASSES

Tags: php, pdo

I am connecting to PDO(PHP DATA OBJECTS) using Inheritance, Let me show you my code of DB.php first.

I have made my DB.php a singleton class. I have well knowledge of singleton pattern.

I want my code to be distributed and separated therefore I have made a brand new class for selecting the data from database.

```
class DB {
private $db = "";
private static $instance = null ;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            //$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase;charset=utf8mb4";
            $this->db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cactus", "root", "", $options = [
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
              ]);
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            print("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>");
            die();
        }
}

    public function connect() {
        if(self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = new DB();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}


<?php
include "DB.php";

class Load_Data {

    public function Fetch() {
        $db = DB::connect();
        $Querystatement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `production`");
        $Querystatement->fetchAll();
        $Querystatement->execute();
        /** Converting data to JSON **/ 
        json_encode($Querystatement);
        return $Querystatement;
    }
}

$load_Data = new Load_Data();
$load_Data->Fetch();
```

Below is my class with name load-data.php, Problem is while calling the DB::connect() it gives me follows error.

[This the image of the error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gViJ4.png)

Error is that it does not recognize "DB::connect();". And ultimately giving a error at prepare function too.

Where am I going wrong? What Should I do to achieve my following desired code.

[NOTE]: I ALREADY HAVE ON STACKOVERFLOW AND AT OTHER FORUMS FOR EXACTLY OR SIMILAR ISSUE BUT FOUND NOTHING THAT COULD HELP.

Comment: Where are you using Inheritance? Are you referring to some other code not shown here?

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is:

```
$db = DB::connect();
^^^
$Querystatement = $this->db->…
                  ^^^^^^^^^
```

Assigning to `$db` creates a local variable called `$db`. If you want to make this value available as an instance variable `$this->db`, you'll need to assign to that explicitly.

Your second problem is that a DB object is not a PDO object; you cannot call PDO methods like `prepare()` on it. Since the `db` property of the `DB` object is private, there's no way to access it from an external caller; you will need to make some changes to your design.

Comment: Actually that will not solve my problem because other half my the error will remain at its place. which is as follows:
"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method DB::prepare() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cactus\Cactus\load-data.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Cactus\Cactus\load-data.php(18): Load_Data->Fetch() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cactus\Cactus\load-data.php on line 8"

In other words it still not recognizing DB()::prepare() method as a legal method

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you have not defined your `connect()` method as a static method. Therefore it cannot be accessed by calling `DB:connect();`

Try modifying your class' `connect()` method to be the following:

```
public static function connect() {
    /* Existing Code Here */
}
```

**EDIT:**

In addition, I think you'll need to make your `$db` property within the class `public` rather than `private` to ensure that the local `$db` variable within your `Fetch` method has visibility of the property to call the `\PDO` methods on.

Comment: @WajahatAli Posted an edit to the answer. You're internal `db` instance is not visible to the local `$db` variable due to the use of private. Make it `public` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems. First, in order to use inheritance the DB class must extend PDO. You are correct that the
constructor should be private, but you shouldn't really have anything in it. Your `connect()` method needs to be static,
and it will need to call another static method to get the instance, and the constructor cannot be static. So add a static `getInstance`
method that sets the instance and returns it, and call that in `connect()` instead of trying to use `new`.

```
<?php
class DB extends PDO {

    private static $instance = null ;

    private function __construct() { }

    private static function getInstance() {
        try {
            return self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=cactus", "root", "", [
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            ]);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print("Error: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>");
            die();
        }
    }

    public static function connect() {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            self::$instance = self::getInstance();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

Now that DB extends PDO, you'll have access to the various PDO methods you need. But there are still several problems with how you're trying to get data. First, you should be calling `prepare()` on `$db` rather than `$this->db`, which does not exist.
After that, you've called `fetchAll()` before `execute()` which won't work, since there's nothing to fetch before you've executed
the statement, you haven't assigned the results of `fetchAll()` or `json_encode()` to anything, and you're returning the PDOStatement
object rather than the array of JSON encoded array of results you're expecting.

```
<?php

class Load_Data {

    public function Fetch() {
        $db = DB::connect();
        $Querystatement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `production`");
        $Querystatement->execute();
        $result = $Querystatement->fetchAll();
        return json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

After fixing `Load_Data`, you still need to make one more adjustment to how you're using it if you want to see anything. Calling
`$load_Data->Fetch();` doesn't output anything. `Fetch()` will return a string now, but you need to `echo` it if you want
to see the results, or assign it to a variable if you're going to do something else with it.

```
<?php
$load_Data = new Load_Data();
echo $load_Data->Fetch();
// OR $json = $load_Data->Fetch();
```

Comment: Sir, Firstly thanks a lot for the in-depth answer to my answer. This is exactly what I wanted, but can you tell me too that how to instantiate the insert() function in the above scenario.

Once again, Thanks a lot Sir.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
$Querystatement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `production`");
```

to

```
$Querystatement = DB::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `production`");
```

Comment: Sir I have just tried it after your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: This would only be true if the variable `$db` contained the `PDO` instance directly. In this case the `$db` variable contains a class reference which contains another variable `$db` that contains the `PDO` instance.

Comment: Exactly. Now, Question is that the logic I am trying to implement is achievable or not? & if yes I need a hint at least  how to achieve it.